# Is it a little bit wordy to say "wake up at 5:00 in the morning"?

Tags: meaning

I guess these 3 sentences are all idiomatic.

1. I usually wake up at 5:00.
2. I usually wake up at 5:00 AM.
3. I usually wake up at 5:00 in the morning.

The last one seems a little bit wordy, isn't it?

Comment: Could you improve the question? Right now you are simply asking for an opinion. And of course “AM” exactly means “in the morning”.

Comment: @djs Thanks for your comments. I am enthusiastic to improve my questions. Would you please give a hint about the aspect I would consider and convey more?